# Normal Random Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

A university expects to receive, for the next academic year, 16000 applications for admission to the bachelor’s degree program. The SAT score obtained by the applicants is modeled as a normal random variable with mean μ = 950 and standard deviation σ = 100. If the university accepts only applicants among the top 25%, what is the minimum SAT score necessary to get accepted into the program?

I'm trying to find the z score for the SAT score, but I don't know how to decide on a proper sample value. Please help!

Comment: How would you go about setting this problem up?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the z score, but I don't know which number to subtract the mean from

Comment: That's a good point.  Do you know the $z$ score, by any chance?

Comment: No, the only information I have is all above.

Comment: Can you use that bit about the top 25 percent to find a $z$ score?

Comment: Is there a way to get the top 25% when I have the mean and the std dv?

Comment: You don't need the mean and standard deviation; all you need is a $z$ chart (or the invNorm function on your TI-83, if you have one).

Comment: I honestly don't know how, I'm struggling and this is why I'm soliciting the help of others. I have a z chart but don't know which column to use. I also have a TI-83 but don't know which numbers to use to get the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit, you wrote that you were looking for a "$z$ score for the SAT score".  Note that the question asks for the SAT score itself.  If what you're seeking is a $z$ score, more often than not, the answer is going to be something like $-5 < z < 5$.  (That's probably a pretty wide interval, but statistics classes like to have students look at outliers; it's probably more, uh, exciting that way :).)  If what you're looking for is an SAT score, though, that's going to be closer to $1000$, especially since we want a *good* SAT score, which is going to be higher than $\mu = 950$.

That's a hint that we *don't* want the $z$ score; that is, we already know the $z$ score.  If we look up $1 - 0.25 = 0.75$ on a $z$ table, we'll get a $z$ score of $0.67$. (We have to look up the probability in the middle of the table itself; once we find $0.75$, or something close to it [on my chart it's $0.7486$], we see what number leads off the row — in this case $0.6$ — and then what number heads the column — in this case $.07$. Putting them together we get $0.67$.) We look for $0.75$ because we want three quarters of the area under the curve to be to the left of the $z$ score. Likewise, if on your TI-83, you press DISTR, select invNorm(, and enter $0.75$, you'll get the same value, just with more accuracy, approximately $0.6745$.

Now you have a $z$ score.  You have $\mu$.  You have $\sigma$.  What don't you have?  (And what is the real-world meaning of that thing you don't have?)  Can you set it up and solve it from here?

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes this makes sense now. So I'll multiply the z score by the std dv and add that to the mean.

Comment: Exactly. What comes out, then, is the $x$ in $(x - \mu) / \sigma$. Note you didn't need the $16000$.